# Combining two dropdown selection to retrive one result ajax/php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I got two dropdowns and  i need to get both values to get data from my database.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.fabric').on('change',function(){
        var fabricID = $(this).val();
        console.log("fabric id_price is " + fabricID); //debugging
        if(fabricID){
           $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'cart_functions.php', 
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                  fabric_id: fabricID
                },
                success:function(html){   
                $('.icms' + id).text(data.val);                                                       


                }
            }); 
      //closing tags


    $('.size').on('change',function(){
        var sizeID = $(this).val();
        if(sizeID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'cart_functions.php',
                 dataType: 'json',
                data:{
                  size_id: sizeID
                },
                success:function(html){
                    $('.icms' + id).text(data.val);
                }
            }); 

//closing tags
```

i'm sending these both values to my calculate.php

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/json');

 include_once '../incluedes/conn_cms.php'; 
 if(isset($_GET["size_id"],$_GET["fabric_id"])){
    $size_id=$_GET["size_id"] ;
    $fabric_id=$_GET["fabric_id"] ;

 $query3 =" SELECT * FROM valores_almofadas 
            WHERE size='$size_id'
            AND   price_id ='$fabric_id'";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query3);
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

            if($_SESSION['estado'] == 'SP'){
              $ICMS = $rows['icms_7'];
             }else{
              $ICMS = $rows['icms_12'];
             }
             $_SESSION['icms']=$ICMS;

        } echo json_encode($_SESSION['icms']);

} 

?>
```

So i select a fabric and then a size fabric value is my id and size is 50 or 45.

fabricid= 1 and size = 50 <-- i am sending this to my calculate.php
So i want to get back the value into a session.
and the result must be on a td..

```
<td class="icms'.$id.'">R$:'.$_SESSION['icms'] .'</td>
```

But its not working, i'm not good at ajax, can you tell me whats wrong and how can i fix these mess?

Comment: And what's `id_price`, are you sure you didn't mean `fabric_id`, and you'd have to send both of those values in each request ?

Comment: yes, i've changed that but forgot to change here too.

Comment: Something like -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/j4p0e5v0/

Comment: yeah this worked, but i only get the value what i refresh the page.

Comment: please can you post your awnser here, so i can select it, for future developer that may get this problem.

Comment: Then try `echo json_encode($ICMS);`

Comment: still didnt work, i tried out using `(document).click(function()` but it didn't work either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125352/discussion-between-james-allan-and-adeneo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure both values are always sent with the request

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fabric, .size').on('change', sendData);

    function sendData() {
        var fabricID = $('.fabric').val();
        var sizeID   = $('.size').val();

        if ( fabricID !== "" && sizeID !== "") {
            $.ajax({
                type     : 'GET',
                url      : 'cart_functions.php',
                dataType : 'json',
                data     : {
                    fabric_id: fabricID,
                    size_id: sizeID
                }
            }).done(function(html) {
                $('.icms' + this.id).text(data.val);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are never sending both values in any ajax call, only one or the other. You need to additionally get the value for `fabric_id` in your `.size` change event and *vice versa*.

Comment: i don't know how to do that, please can you give me an example how to do that?

Comment: I would but it looks like @adeneo has beaten me to it... ;-)